# Getting undefined when calling a property within an array in state within render section?

Tags: reactjs, json, react-state

would anyone be able to help.  For some reason I can console.log this property but I cannot put it in within the render section of a react component.

This returns undefined

```
  render() {
    return (
        <header className="menu">
                <div>
                    {this.state.sampleValue}
                    {this.state.items.data[0].name}
                </div>
            </div>
        </header>
    );
}
```

but yet I can console.log the same property fine outside of the render section?

```
    console.log(this.state.items.data[0].name)
```

The sampleValue property works fine.

I'm using componentDidMount to make an api call that is stored with this.state.items

Comment: Please share a [mcve].

Comment: Updated example is this enough?

Comment: Thanks, it's better, but still somewhat unclear, since we don't know what the response shape looks like. Is the result `{data: [...]}`? If so, your code should be OK other than the fact that `.data` won't be available on the empty array in your state initially on the first render, so you'll need to handle that with `this.state.items.data[0]?.name`. If the result is `[...]`, then you want to render with `this.state.items[0]?.name`. It seems like there'd be an error either way, though, so if you're not seeing any problems in the console, that's surprising.

Comment: Hi added the response if that helps, also I wonder if it's something about how that "data" object is getting passed from backend

Comment: The log you showed isn't the response, that's the full state after the response is set. Seems fine to me, so my above remarks still stand.

Comment: ok I tried this `this.state.items.data[0]?.name` but got error still.  Maybe one thing I don't understand is will items this.state.items won't be available until after a certain action takes place?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/251162/discussion-between-stephen-selvey-and-ggorlen).

Answer (score 0):

The problem was I was using this api call syntax which seems to make you use if / else on the isLoading property in order to display the data within render.

```
    componentDidMount() {
    axios.get("http://localhost:3035/").then(
        result => {
          this.setState({
            isLoaded: true,
            items: result.data
          });
        },
        // Note: it's important to handle errors here
        // instead of a catch() block so that we don't swallow
        // exceptions from actual bugs in components.
        error => {
          this.setState({
            isLoaded: true,
            error
          });
        }
        );
    }
```